# how to install pod2html on msys2

Tags: pacman, msys2

openssl build is missing pod2hml and i do not know how to install it.
since pod2html is a perl package I tried to find a way to install it but ppm seems not available from pacman since

```
pacman -S ppm
```

doesn't return anything.

How would it be possible to install pod2html on msys2, preferably using pacman ?

Comment: You may search [MINGW-packages](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages) or [msys2-packages](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages).

Comment: thanks @Biswapriyo interesting pair of links but I couldn't find pod2html nor ppm in neither

Comment: Does msys2 have those packages? Any article where you read about them?

Comment: @Biswapriyo  no , this the reason of my question